# Quelle est la différence entre un rameau et une branche?

Tags: vocabulaire

Quelle est la différence entre un rameau et une branche dans le sens littéral et dans le sens figuré ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un rameau est une petite branche, que ce soit au sens propre ou au sens figuré.

Rameau est plus poétique et beaucoup moins utilisé que branche, environ dix fois moins d'après Google books.

Rameau sert à construire quelques locutions comme *rameau d'olivier* et *rameau d'or*.